Why do cout and printf produce different results?
I'm learning C/C++ and started to try out programing with big numbers but when printing them I get a strange error.
Here is my example code:
unsigned long long shiftresult = 1ULL;
for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++) {
    shiftresult = (1ULL << i);
    printf("%lld << %d = %lld\n", 1ULL, i, shiftresult);
    cout << 1ULL << " << " << i << " = " << shiftresult << endl;
}

The problem being that when the loop reaches i = 63 printf prints -9223372036854775808 while cout prints 9223372036854775808 which is the "real" output.
Could someone explain why this happens?

The -Wformat gcc option can help you: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wformat

How do you format an unsigned long long int using printf?

The short answer is "printf is more fragile".

I'd argue that the C tag should stay as it's a question about C APIs vs C++ APIs.  The dups are also tagged C.

Because they do not use the same code. Side note, from C++20 use std::format and from C++23 use std::print for formatting output.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

You're using the wrong format specifier for printf.
The %lld format specifier expects a long long argument, but you're passing an unsigned long long argument, so the unsigned number is being interpreted as a signed number.
You need to use %llu to print an unsigned long long.

If there is a mismatch between the format specifier and the type of the corresponding argument,  printf() has undefined behaviour.

Because you told printf to print %lld (a signed long long), but your value is actually an unsigned long long, which should be printed with %llu. output streams can figure that out automatically, printf has to be told.
